# R, Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors in fastai

Tags: r, fast-ai, dataloader

Running **CollabDataLoaders()** in implementing fastai using R in the code below:

```
library(fastai)
library(zeallot)
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

URLs_MOVIE_LENS_ML_100k()

c(user, item, title) %<-% list('userId', 'movieId', 'title')

ratings = fread('ml-100k/u.data', col.names = c(user,item,'rating','timestamp'))
movies = fread('ml-100k/u.item', col.names = c(item, 'title', 'date', 'N', 'url',
                                               paste('g',1:19,sep = '')))

rating_movie = ratings[movies[, .SD, .SDcols=c(item,title)], on = item]

dls = CollabDataLoaders_from_df(rating_movie, seed=42, valid_pct=0.1, bs=64, item_name=title, path='ml-100k')
```

Encountered an error in the last line:

```
dls = CollabDataLoaders_from_df(rating_movie, seed=42, valid_pct=0.1, bs=64, item_name=title, path='ml-100k')
```

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

**rating_movie** is a data frame object without NA.
Appreciate if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

I can show you the efforts I made to get past this error on a Mac running R 4.2.

```
> traceback()
2: do.call(collab()$CollabDataLoaders$from_df, args)
1: CollabDataLoaders_from_df(rating_movie, seed = 42, valid_pct = 0.1, 
       bs = 64, item_name = title, path = "ml-100k")
> collab()$CollabDataLoaders$from_df
Error in collab() : could not find function "collab"
> ??collab
> library(collab)
Error in library(collab) : there is no package called ‘collab’
> library(fastai)
> collab()$CollabDataLoaders$from_df
Error in collab() : could not find function "collab"
> fastai::collab()$CollabDataLoaders$from_df
Error: 'collab' is not an exported object from 'namespace:fastai'
> fastai:::collab()$CollabDataLoaders$from_df
Error in fastai:::collab()$CollabDataLoaders : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> fastai:::collab()
> fastai:::collab
function () 
{
    try(collab <- reticulate::import("fastai.collab"), TRUE)
}
<bytecode: 0x7f93b938b6d0>
<environment: namespace:fastai>
> python_path()
Error in python_path() : could not find function "python_path"
> fastai:::python_path()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/fastai/python"
> reticulate::import("fastai.collab")
Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastai'
> install_fastai()
```

After a long series of messages about the installation of a large number of python modules I finally got past that error.

```
c(user,item,title)  %<-% list('userId','movieId','title')
  ratings = fread('ml-100k/u.data', col.names = c(user,item, 'rating','timestamp'))
movies = fread('ml-100k/u.item', col.names = c(item, 'title', 'date', 'N', 'url', paste('g',1:19,sep = '')))
rating_movie = ratings[movies[, .SD, SDcols=c(item,title)], on = item]
dls = CollabDataLoaders_from_df(rating_movie, seed = 42, valid_pct = 0.1, bs = 64, item_name=title, path='ml-100k')

#/Users/my_name/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastai/torch_core.py:263: UserWarning: 'has_mps' is deprecated, please use 'torch.backends.mps.is_built()'
  return getattr(torch, 'has_mps', False)

str(dls)

#<fastai.tabular.data.TabularDataLoaders object at <x7f93aa8ddd00>

class(dls)
#[1] "fastai.tabular.data.TabularDataLoaders" "fastai.data.core.DataLoaders"           "fastcore.basics.GetAttr"               
$[4] "python.builtin.object"
```

But I did get the warning above but that is up to the fastai author to fix.